# Getting an error when trying to create a user in my Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running this playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: New user is created
  hosts: machine2
  become: true

  vars:
    username: test
    
  tasks:
    - name: User gets created
      user:
        name: " {{ username }}"
        state: present
```

However, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Hi Marty and welcome, It's better if you copy paste your code (and put it in code block for syntax highlight) than provide an screenshot. It helps the bot for indexing and people to copy-past an error message and google it for example.

Answer (score 0):

Review the line where you use the variable username. So far there's a blank space. It should be:

`name: "{{username}}"`.

You can see in the second image that it is complaining because it tries to create the user ' test' (with a blank space at the beginning). Anyway, for debugging purposes it might become handy to use the -v flat when launching the playbook. You can use:

```
ansible-playbook example.yml -v
ansible-playbook example.yml -vv
ansible-playbook example.yml -vvv
ansible-playbook example.yml -vvvv
```

Each v will increase the verbosity level.

Answer (score 0):

### The issue

The problem is than you have an extra space before you variable

```yaml
  name: " {{ username }}"
```

It should be:

```yaml
  name: "{{ username }}"
```

### Explanation for beginner

It's actually some jinja2 templating. You have set the variable `username` with "`test`" as content. So if in `" {{ username }}"` you replace `{{ username }}` by `test` you ends up with `" test"`. Note the space before the first curly bracket remains and comes before "test". And the system does not accept to create a user with a usernamer starting with a space.